# Reason that too small photos don't upload to Google Photos

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

When I sync a local photos directory to Google Drive/Photos, Google Backup and Sync fails to upload small sized photos.

I reckon this is due to Google's choice rather that technical considerations with small sized photos. Is my assumption here correct? If so, what would be the reasons Google refused to upload small sized photos using Backup and Sync?

--

[image: Example]